# Mac is really slow and I can't get Apps to open

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, imac, performance

When I try to open an App it does nothing. I go online and it is extremely slow. I have tried some of the idea's on here but, nothing has helped. I also tried to download a Clean up program. It isn't compatible for my Mac. I have a OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Please tell us what the specs of your mac are, without this information it is difficult to help.
Think: ram, model, processor

Comment: 4GB memory, 3.06 Ghz Intel core 2, Imac 10,1

Comment: Open the Activity monitor and see who is slowing it down.

Comment: Will deleting things in Activity Monitor mess anything up?

Comment: Deleting some things is not good. Clicking on the column label with '% CPU' to make it blue with a down arrow may show a 'cpu hog' that you can report back with. Another suggestion is to restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Open Activity Monitor and see if something is using an excessive amount of CPU.

Open disk utility and mark your volume.
Check how much Space is available on your drive.
Verify hdd and volume.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to reboot the Mac.

Next, check the amount of hard drive space you have - if it is less than 10% of the drive size or less than four or five times the size of RAM you may be getting problems with the OS finding swap space or being able to defrag the drive.

Then you might install [AppleJack](http://applejack.sourceforge.net/) and give it a run.

Next, using Disk Utility run a verify on the drive.

After that uninstall any utilities that live in your menu bar.

If at that point you are still running slow then I would do a clean install of the operating system and **don't** use Migration Assistant to migrate any applications or settings.